# How do I disable an Azure Advisor recommendation infinitely using PowerShell?

Tags: azure, powershell

I am trying to use the `Disable-AzAdvisorRecommendation`command from az.advisor PowerShell module to disable recommendations from Azure advisor for an infinite period.
Using the -days parameter I can disable an alert for 'n' days. How can I disable the alerts permanently for an infinite period?

P.S: There are alternatives to achieve this from az cli but however I would need to this work with PowerShell

Answer (score 1):

Based on the example [`here`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.advisor/disable-azadvisorrecommendation?view=azps-2.6.0#examples), if you omit `-Days` parameter, alerts are disabled for infinite duration.

Comment: Please accept the answer if it solved your problem.